# Selected cells CGridCtrl from codeproject

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I need to find selected cells for the control CGridCtrl using the following code.

```
CCellRange cells = m_Grid.GetSelectedCellRange();
if( cells.Count() == 0 )
    return ;
    for (int i = cells.GetMaxRow(); i >= cells.GetMinRow(); i--)
    {
        for (int j=cells.GetMinCol(); j<=cells.GetMaxCol();j++)
        {
            BOOL selected = m_Grid.GetCell(i,j)->IsSelected();
            TRACE(_T("Row %d Column %d Selected = %d State %d\n"),i,j,selected, m_Grid.GetCell(i,j)->GetState());
            if(selected)
            {
                            m_Grid.DeleteRow(i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Since the cells I selected are not contiguous, I need to use IsSelected() to find a cell selected. The only last cell return TRUE. Is there a way to determine the cells selected for the control?

Comment: What's wrong with your implementation?

Comment: Nothing wrong. There may be a bug in the grid control. I wonder if anyone sees the same thing or there is already a solution available.

Comment: I found the problem, DeleteRow method de-selects all cells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if the flag in the cells are correct, but the correct function to check if a cell is selected are:

```
BOOL CGridCtrl::IsCellSelected(CCellID &cell) const
BOOL CGridCtrl::IsCellSelected(int nRow, int nCol) const
```

Just check the implementation. There is a m_SelectedCellMap that contains all selected ranges.